# How to get number of documents by using find method express js?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

How to get number of documents find total express js? I have searched in google and StackOverflow. But I could not find. what people saying is use `countDocuments` to get number of documents of the Model like following:

```
UserModel.countDocuments(function(err,count){ 
  count
  res.render('index',{count:count}); // returning count and rendering to index.ejs
});
```

But I want both resultset and at the same time `recordcount` like following

```
UserModel.find(function(err,data){
    res.render('index',{data:data,count:data.count});
});
```

Comment: `data` is an array so `data.length` will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UserModel.find() returns an array, so you can just go ahead and run: res.render('index',{data:data,count:data.length});

Answer (score 0):

```
UserModel.find({}, null, options).exec().then(data => {
        UserModel.count({}, (err, counts) => {
            if (err) {
                           res.send(err)

            } else {
                res.render('index',{data:data,count:data.counts});

            }
        })
    }).catch(err => {
           res.send(err)
    });
```

Comment: You are trying to call UserModel 2 times. one for getting all the records and another for getting count. Is there any other solutions to get both data and count in a single call.

Comment: that is single api call only,usermodel is the tablename thatsall

Comment: Yes that is working fine. Is it the only way and right way ? .  I have wrote following code and it is working fine. Is it fine way to pulling the data? 


  User.find().then(UserData => {
  User.countDocuments().then(UserCount=>{
    Category.find().then(CategoryData=>{
      Category.countDocuments().
            res.render('index',{categoryCount:CategoryCount,userCount:UserCount,userData:UserData,CategoryData:CategoryData});
          });
        });
  });

Comment: It will work but it seems a bit redundant. `UserModel.find()` returns an array, so you can just go ahead and run: 
    `res.render('index',{data:data,count:data.length});`

Comment: Super!. Thank you so much Seal Rapolai. That's what i want. :)

Answer (score 0):

Since `UserModel.find()` returns an array, you can just return the count from `data.length`.

Also, just note that `Model.count()` has been deprecated in the latest mongoose version (v5.7.6). If you are adamant on using it or something similar, you can use one of the following:

- `Model.estimatedDocumentCount()` (fast): which uses the collection's metadata to give you an **estimate** of the number of documents, [see docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.estimatedDocumentCount).
- `Model.countDocuments()` (can be slow for large collections): for a more accurate count. [see docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.countDocuments).